# Deploy Azure functions with Python from VS Code, function disappears after WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE app setting

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

I deployed an Azure function written in Python from local VS Code.
After I deployed the function, I got the warning on "function" page saying:

> Your app is currently in read only mode because you are running from a package file. To make any changes update the content in your zip file and WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE app setting.

According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/run-functions-from-deployment-package
I manually upload the zip file of my function to blob storage, then went to the "Configuration" and set the application "WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE" to the URL of the storage (.zip file).

But once I set the WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE, and saved, my function will just disappear on my functions page...

[image]

What happened?

Answer (score 0):

Generally this means one of:

- Your function can't connect to the Storage account, verify your App config for 'AzureWebJobsStorage' is correct or the managed identity for the function has access to it
- The URL is incorrect
- The ZIP package is corrupt, incorrectly structured or invalid

If you have App Insights or Diagnostics setup you may find more details in there - it can be hit and miss though.

Assuming you're using GitHub, you will probably find either directly connecting the repo to the function or pushing the code via Action will be easier than manual uploads